# <wand.img> saving several png files as photoshop psd file converts the color into grayscale

Tags: python, photoshop, wand

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="base.png") as img:
    img.read(filename="background.png")
    img.read(filename="image.png")
    img.read(filename="sub_box.png")
    img.read(filename="cta_box.png")
    img.read(filename="sub_text.png")
    img.read(filename="cta_text.png")
    img.save(filename="final.psd")
```

I wrote this code to stack png images into a psd file

The code does work, the file has all the layers, but the color is all grayscale
(png images aren't grayscale)

https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.13/wand/image.html

Any ideas for solving this problem?

I tried to change the image.format to psd, checked the image.colorspace but couldn't solve the problem

Comment: A [mcve] of a multi-image stack that doesn't work would be a 2-image stack and providing both images.

Comment: The problem was quite simple: When I changed the first line to <with Image(filename="background.png") as img:>, It solved the problem
btw @MarkSetchell thanks for pointing out! I'll follow those rules next time:)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so other folks can see a method that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image() as img:
    with Image(filename="base.png") as base:
        img.composite(base, 0, 0)
    layer_img_pth= ["background.png", "image.png", "sub_box.png", "cta_box.png", "sub_text.png", "cta_text.png"]
    for layer in layer_img_pth:
        with Image(filename=layer) as layer_img:
            img.composite(layer_img, 0, 0)
    img.format = 'psd'
    img.save(filename="final.psd")
```

This will help you stack images one over other. Also if have examples of files please attach it to question itself.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. You are ***compositing*** multiple images, which combines them into a single image. I *think* OP was trying to make a multi-image PSD which contains multiple, ***separate*** images. I *think*, but that's why I asked OP to share full working code‍♂️

Comment: He is asking for stacking images one over another. I thought that is the case so the solution is for the same. It is mentioned in the problem statement of OP. But yes we need some more clarification on the matter. And also I assumed it since photoshop is needed for stacking images one over other

Comment: I think the fact OP says *"the file has all the layers"* implies he wants the images to remain as separate layers, rather than be composited into a single layer... along with the use of the word ***stack*** which doesn't seem correct for a single, composited image. But I really don't know - you may well be right‍♂️

Comment: @MarkSetchell you might be right and I am 80% after seeing the solution by OP.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was quite simple:

When I changed the code like this,

```
with Image(filename="base.png") as img:
    img.read(filename="base.png")
    img.read(filename="background.png")
    img.read(filename="image.png")
    img.read(filename="sub_box.png")
    img.read(filename="cta_box.png")
    img.read(filename="sub_text.png")
    img.read(filename="cta_text.png")
    img.save(filename="final.psd")
```

It solved the issue

I guess you should first read the file you opened for some reason

Comment: Please show a ***complete*** properly-formatted example of making a multi-image stack so future visitors can readily see complete, working code. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).